# Is there a way to save a `$(this)` selector as a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of form inputs with errors status below them set up as follows (simplified version).

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-field">
        <input type="text" class="input-field" />
      </div>
    <div>
  </div>
  <div class="error-msg">
   Field cannot be blank
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to create a simple, generic Javascript function that checks for a null input for each field and hides/shows the error element. I am using `.each` to cycle through each instance of `input-wrapper` and check if `input` field value is null:

```
$(".input-wrapper").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".input-field").blur(function() {
        let val = $(this).val();
        if (val == 0 || val == null) {
            // Show error
        }
    });
});
```

However, I am having trouble accessing the `error-msg` element relevant its the input.

I can use `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.error-msg').show()` but that seems too sloppy.

`.closest()`, eg: `$(this).closest(".input-wrapper").find(".error-msg").show();` does not work (I think because it does not take CSS selectors).

`.next()`, eg: `$(this).next(".error-msg").show();` is not working either - I'm not sure why.

I've tried saving the current `.input-wrapper` in a var, but no luck there either:

```
$(".input-wrapper").each(function() {
    let thisWrapper = $(this);
    $(this).find(".input-field").blur(function() {
        let val = $(this).val();
        if (val == 0 || val == null) {
            thisWrapper.find(".error-msg").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Short of making a whole seperate function outside of this just to hide/show the error message, would anyone know how to pull this off?

Comment: `.closest()` [does take a CSS selector](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) as the first argument. Shouldn't the 7th line in your HTML be `</div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is how you test the input value against integer `0` and `null`, instead of `""` (empty string).

I'm a performance junkie and strongly advocate against using bloatware jquery for simple tasks like this, especially when you are dealing with a single element.
*(like seriously, what's the point of using nonsense like `$(this).val()` for a single element when you can simply use `this.value` ???)*

You don't really need access to the `.error-msg` in this particular case, simply add an `error` class to the wrapper when `input` is empty, and control `.error-msg` visibility via css. This way, you can also style other elements at the same time:

```js
//get all wrappers as node list
const nlInputWrapper = document.querySelectorAll(".input-wrapper");
for(let i = 0; i < nlInputWrapper.length; i++)
{
  const elInputWrapper = nlInputWrapper[i];
  const elInput = elInputWrapper.querySelector("input.input-field");
  elInput.addEventListener("blur", () => 
  {
    const isEmpty = elInput.value.trim() === "";
    //add "error" class to the wrapper if input is empty
    elInputWrapper.classList.toggle("error", isEmpty);
  });

  //remove "error" class when value changed, even if it's empty
  elInput.addEventListener("input", () => elInputWrapper.classList.remove("error"));

}
```

```css
.error-msg
{
  display: none;
}

.input-wrapper.error .error-msg
{
  display: block;
}

.input-wrapper.error .input-field
{
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-field">
        <input type="text" class="input-field" />
      </div>
    <div>
  </div>
  <div class="error-msg">
   Field cannot be blank
  </div>
</div>
```

If you insist on using jquery, avoid duplicating queries like `$(this)`, Store it in a variable and use it instead:

```js
$(".input-wrapper").each(function() {
    //for better readability
    //using "$" as variable prefix
    //to identify that it contains jquery object
    const $thisWrapper = $(this);
    const $errorMsg = $thisWrapper.find(".error-msg");
    $thisWrapper.find(".input-field").blur(function() {
        const $input = $(this);
        const isEmpty = $input.val() === "";
        $errorMsg.toggle(isEmpty);
    });
});
```

```css
.error-msg
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-field">
        <input type="text" class="input-field" />
      </div>
    <div>
  </div>
  <div class="error-msg">
   Field cannot be blank
  </div>
</div>
```

(note that `$thisWrapper.find(".error-msg")` was moved to the outside of the event handler function, no need search for this element on each event!)